# How does R handle common dependencies?

Tags: r

How does R handle dependencies when 2 or more packages have a common dependency, when using `install.packages()` to install from CRAN?

I understand the general default is to assume that the most recent version of a package on CRAN works with the other most recent packages on CRAN.

But what happens if:

- I install `package_1` from CRAN, which depends on `dependency_1` v 1.0, so I have both these on my system.
- Sometime later I try to install `package_2`, which also depends on `dependency_1` version >=2.0, which is now available on CRAN.
- I assume doing this would try to update `dependency_1` to v 2.0
- At this point my installed version of `package_1` is now out of date with CRAN, where `package_1` now has `dependency_1` version >=2.0 also.
- Unfortunately, this means my installed version of `package_1` is relying on certain behaviour from `dependency_1` which isn't present in v2.0, and so consequently won't work any more

At this point, will R:

- Check `package_1` is up to date, and update it accordingly along with `dependency_1`, when installing `package_2`?
- Identify the potential conflict, and fail to install `package_2`?
- Install `package_2`, update `dependency_1`, and leave me to find the conflict between my version of `package_1` and `dependency_1`?
- Do something else I haven't thought of?!

Comment: If all packages are on CRAN they are checked that they work with the existing dependencies on CRAN (and Bioconductor). If this is not catch by CRAN you can open a bug report or send an email to the package maintainer who declared a dependency to a version which is no longer true.

Comment: Thank you. So in my hypothetical situation, `package_1` wouldn't explicitly have `dependency_1` == 1.0, so I don't think it could know that v2.0 doesn't work. But does R update it anyway, because it depends on `dependency_1`, which R has now updated when installing `package-2`?

Comment: And just to clarify, `package_1` on CRAN would be working fine with the latest version of `dependency_1`. This is just because I and haven't updated my local packages for a while. (I've seen this situation a lot, where users install a package and then forget about it.)

Comment: Can you clarify your question slightly to emphasize/assert that the version of `package_1` on your system (which is dependent on an older version of `dependency_1`) would be out of date with CRAN (where there would be a newer version of `package_1` which worked with the newer version of `dependency_1`?  (I'm pretty sure your option 3 is the answer, but I wouldn't know for sure without testing and/or staring at the source code ...

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect comment from @BenBolker

Comment: @s_pike If `package_2` has a `dependency_1 >= 2.0` then R updates `dependency_1` it because it is needed by `package_2`. Not because `package_1` needs it.

Comment: Thanks Ilrs, sorry if it's not clear in the question. In this case, the outdated local version of `package_1` doesn't work with `dependency_1 v2.0`. The updated version on CRAN now has a new requirement for `dependency_1` to be >=2.0, but this isn't installed locally yet.